# Develop a decreasing price function by step

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to configure my price list. The price unit must decrease depending the quantity you buy but should keep growing.

I was able to do it in excel, but now I would like to do a function in javascript.

my pricelist in the DB is like this:

```
min max price
1   9   50
10  19  45
20  29  40
30  49  35
50  79  30
80  90  25
```

The function depending the price is

```
qty price function
1-9 qty*50
10-19 (qty-9)*45+(9*50)
20-29 (qty-19)*40+(19*45)
...
80-90 (qty-79)*25+(79*30)
```

I would like to create a ES6 function that receive the quantity in parameter and return the total price.

**UPDATE**
I was able to create the function but I'm pretty sure that we can improve it.

```
let priceList= [
{"_id":1,"min":1,"max":9,"price":50},
{"_id":2,"min":10,"max":19,"price":45},
{"_id":3,"min":20,"max":29,"price":40},
{"_id":4,"min":30,"max":49,"price":35},
{"_id":5,"min":50,"max":79,"price":30},
{"_id":6,"min":80,"max":90,"price":25}
]

function sum(qty){
  let sum = 0;
  let prices = priceList.filter((x)=>x.min<=qty);
  var price;
  var priceArr=[];
  const pricesLength = prices.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < pricesLength ; i++) {
    price = prices[i];
    if(i==0){
        priceArr.push(price.price * ((price.max < qty) ? price.max : qty));
    } else {
        priceArr.push(price.price * ((price.max <= qty) ? price.max - price.min + 1 : qty - price.min + 1) + priceArr[i-1]);
    }
  }
  return priceArr[pricesLength-1];

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jm7teuqb/1/

Comment: You should give it a try, and show any errors you have. That way we can understand what you're having difficulty with. We don't typically just write out full answers on StackOverflow, that's not as useful to the entire community. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Here's something to get you started https://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/rdf8szu3/

Comment: please show what did you try to implement in js

Comment: I tried with the first approach that was deleted. By doing a reduce of my array and multiply the unit price, but then I realized that it doesn't work. I will try again

Comment: I'm nearly it but I'm sure we can optimize by using ES6 https://jsfiddle.net/g531cuva/3/